# How can I disable deletion and focus on a BlockEmbed

Tags: quill

I have a special blot that extends BlockEmbed. I would like to disable focus and backspace deletion in this block. Is this possible?

```
import Quill from 'quill';
import { html, render } from 'lit-html'

let Block = Quill.import('blots/block');
let BlockEmbed = Quill.import('blots/block/embed');

const template = (text) => html`
  <img src="https://prosemirror.net/img/dino/tyrannosaurus.png"/>
  <span>${text}</span>`;

export class BlockActionBlot extends BlockEmbed {
  static blotName = 'action';
  static className = 'block-action';
  static tagName = 'div';

  static create({ id, text }) {

    const node = super.create();
    node.dataset.text = text;
    node.dataset.id = id;

    render(template(text), node)

    return node;
  }

    static value(node) {
    return {
      id: node.dataset.id,
      text: node.dataset.text
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your blot to be "static", the easiest way I found was to set `node.contentEditable` to `false` in the `create` method.

I hope this helps and the answer's not too late in your case (I ran into the very same issue today)...

Answer (score 0):

To disable deletion you could override the `deleteAt()` method in the `BlockActionBlot`. Something like the following below. That should prevent deletion at the blot level.

```
export class BlockActionBlot extends BlockEmbed {
   // ...
   deleteAt() { }
}
```

See the [blot methods](https://github.com/quilljs/parchment#blots) for the signature of `deleteAt` and the other methods provided.

For disabling focus on the blot you could apply `user-select: none` and/or `cursor: none` to the blot. You'll probably want to add a `class` for the above css properties in the `create` method you have. You could do that with `node.setAttribute('class', 'block-action')` then apply the css to `div.block-action` in your loaded css.

Another option would be to try and intercept the delete key press. I think that approach, though doable, would be more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1 (assumption)**. You have a custom blot class that extends something like `BlockEmbed`

**Step 2.**
Add the following to your custom blot class:

```
deleteAt() {
  return false
}
```

to your custom blot class.

**Step 3.**
Set `contenteditable` to false when creating the blot in the `create` method

```
node.setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
```